# Continuously run function even if component unmounts?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, lifecycle

Lets say I have a function in a lifecycle method of a component like so

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.taskRunner();
}

taskRunner() {
  setInterval((function(scope){
    return function(){
      scope.props.callApiandRecordtoDatabase();
    };
  })(this),360000);
}
```

Will this process keep running on a hosted site if no one is currently visiting the page? How could I ensure that it does?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't explicitly clean the timer, it will continue running. That's why it's recommended that you clean stuff on `componentWillUnmount()`. As React docs says:

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any subscriptions that were created in componentDidMount().

Answer (score 0):

> Will this process keep running on a hosted site if no one is currently visiting the page?

No, it will not. I think you're confusing the concept of client and server. ReactJS will run on the client (i.e. a browser like Google Chrome). If that script is executed and the component unmounts, it will still be held in memory and the function will execute after 360,000 ms unless the JavaScript process is stopped, which will most likely happen if the user closes the tab which executed that script. You can play with an example I set up on WebpackBin here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KyTgz4IOADwQYHiTvz9.

What are you trying to accomplish? It doesn't hurt to add some context to your questions and the community may be able to suggest a more appropriate solution that you possibly did not consider before.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to make an api call at an interval, store in the db, query the newly updated set of data and present the data on the page. So it does works like you said when the client is open, and not otherwise. I'm most concerned with that data from the api getting saved every hour...would then moving that function to the backend be the solution? Or is there another approach I'm not considering